# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.j3d.aviatrix3d.output.graphics.SimpleAWTSurface cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComponent

Tags: java, classcastexception

I'm trying to create a Java class that imports X3D models and displays them. And I have the X3D model called `test.x3d` saved in the Netbeans project. My code is

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.web3d.x3d.sai.*;
import org.xj3d.sai.Xj3DBrowser;

public class Xj3DSpecificDemo extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DSpecificDemo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        // Setup browser parameters
        HashMap requestedParameters=new HashMap();
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ShowConsole",Boolean.FALSE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_FPSShown", Boolean.TRUE);

        // Create an SAI component
        X3DComponent x3dComp = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(requestedParameters);

        // Add the component to the UI
        JComponent x3dPanel = (JComponent)x3dComp.getImplementation();
        contentPane.add(x3dPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Get an external browser
        ExternalBrowser x3dBrowser = x3dComp.getBrowser();

        boolean useXj3D = true;

        if (x3dBrowser.getName().indexOf("Xj3D") < 0) {
            System.out.println("Not running on Xj3D, extended functions disabled");
            useXj3D = false;
        }
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);


        // Create an X3D scene by loading a file
        X3DScene mainScene = x3dBrowser.createX3DFromURL(new String[] { "test.x3d" });

        // Replace the current world with the new one
        x3dBrowser.replaceWorld(mainScene);

        if (!useXj3D)
            return;

        Xj3DBrowser xj3dBrowser = (Xj3DBrowser) x3dBrowser;
        xj3dBrowser.setMinimumFrameInterval(1000 / 15);

        boolean lines = true;

        while(true) {
            if (lines) {
                xj3dBrowser.setRenderingStyle(Xj3DBrowser.RENDER_LINES);
                lines = false;
            } else {
                xj3dBrowser.setRenderingStyle(Xj3DBrowser.RENDER_SHADED);
                lines = true;
            }

            try { Thread.sleep(250); } catch(Exception e) {}
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Xj3DSpecificDemo demo = new Xj3DSpecificDemo();
    }

}
```

And the error that I'm getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.j3d.aviatrix3d.output.graphics.SimpleAWTSurface cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComponent
    at Xj3DSpecificDemo.<init>(Xj3DSpecificDemo.java:44)
    at Xj3DSpecificDemo.main(Xj3DSpecificDemo.java:95)
```

But I can't seem to find the `aviatrix3d jar` anywhere to download

**EDIT**

After downloading the `aviatrix3d jar` I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.j3d.aviatrix3d.output.graphics.SimpleAWTSurface cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComponent
    at Xj3DSpecificDemo.<init>(Xj3DSpecificDemo.java:23)
    at Xj3DSpecificDemo.main(Xj3DSpecificDemo.java:69)
```

**EDIT#2**

I've also tried it with the following code so I believe it's one of the `Jars` as I'm getting the same error

```
package simplesaidemo1;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.*;

public class SimpleSAIDemo1 extends JFrame{
    public SimpleSAIDemo1() {
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        // Create an SAI component
        X3DComponent x3dComp = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(null);

        // Add the component to the UI
        JComponent x3dPanel = (JComponent)x3dComp.getImplementation();
        contentPane.add(x3dPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Get an external browser
        ExternalBrowser x3dBrowser = x3dComp.getBrowser();

        // Create an X3D scene by loading a file
        X3DScene mainScene = x3dBrowser.createX3DFromURL(new String[] { "test.x3d" });

        // Replace the current world with the new one
        x3dBrowser.replaceWorld(mainScene);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleSAIDemo1 demo = new SimpleSAIDemo1();
    }    
}
```

The only difference is the following lines it says the error is on

```
at simplesaidemo1.SimpleSAIDemo1.<init>(SimpleSAIDemo1.java:17)
at simplesaidemo1.SimpleSAIDemo1.main(SimpleSAIDemo1.java:30)
```

Comment: [`SimpleAWTSurface`](http://aviatrix3d.j3d.org/javadoc/index.html) is not an instance of [`JComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html), yet you treat it as one. How do you expect this to work? By the way, the jar can be downloaded from [here](http://aviatrix3d.j3d.org/download.html).

Comment: @bcsb1001 Thanks for the link for the jar file :) when I programmed the code, I was unaware that I called `SimpleAWTSurface` as an instance of `JComponent`

Comment: Well, the stacktrace tells you fairly straightforwardly. The line it points to shows you clearly performing that cast. Also, please use Google if you want to find a jar - I'm not familiar with this library but I found its jar as the top result.

Comment: @bcsb1001 so it would be on lines 23 and 69?

Comment: Line 23, called from line 69.

Comment: @bcsb1001 It might be a long shot, but do you know how to fix it? Because I've looked online for help on the error but I can't find a way

Comment: I've told you. You're trying to treat something that isn't a `JComponent` as one. I don't know what you are trying to do, but this clearly isn't right.

Comment: @bcsb1001 I'm trying to display X3D models in Java